# Recurrence relation $a_{n+2}=K^{2}a_{n+1}−a_{n}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, contest-math

Let K be an integer. We define the sequence $(a_{n})$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_{0} = 0, a_{1}= K$
$$a_{n+2}=K^{2}a_{n+1}−a_{n}$$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Prove that $a_{n}a_{n+1} + 1$ divides $a_{n}^2 + a_{n+1}^2$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $k=0$ We can show that $a_{n}= 0$  so $1$ will divide $0$.

One can also check for $k=1$ and $-1$, that $\vert a_{n}\vert\leq1$ and easily show that $a_{n}a_{n+1} + 1$ divides $a_{n}^2 + a_{n+1}^2$.

However for $K\geq2$ we have our recurrence relation with the general term
$$a_{n} = C_{1}x_{1}^{n}+C_{2}x_{2}^{n}$$

From initial values

$$a_{0} = C_{1} + C_{2} = 0,\quad so\quad  C_{2}=-C_{1}$$
and from characteristic polynomial $x^{2}-K^{2}x+1 = 0$ of the recurrence relation and Viet's theorem one can claim that $$x_{2}=\frac{1}{x_{1}}.$$

After taking $$a_{n}^{2} = C_{1}^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2n}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n}}\right)-2C_{1}^{2}$$
$$a_{n+1}^{2} = C_{1}^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2n+2}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n+2}}\right)-2C_{1}^{2}$$
and
$$a_{n}a_{n+1}+1 = C_{1}^{2}\left(x_{1}^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n+1}}\right)-K^{2}C_{1}^{2}+1$$
we  can find relation $$\left(x_{1}^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n+1}}\right)\left(x_{1}+\frac{1}{x_{1}}\right) = x_{1}^{2n}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n}} +x_{1}^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2n+1}}$$.

also from Viet's theorem we can find that: $$x_{1} + x_{2} = x_{1} + \frac{1}{x_{1}} = K^{2}$$

P.S. Is it useful to find that $$C_{1} = K^{6}-4K^2$$ and the main question am I doing everything right?

Comment: Looks good. You can also do this by induction. Check that the first few quotients are all $K^2$ and conjecture that $a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2=K^2(a_na_{n+1}+1)$ for $n\ge 0$, then prove it by induction on $n$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Wow. Thanks!

Comment: Note: While it is true that determining $a_i$ explicitly and substituting that into the question should eventually prove it, it's not clear to me that you are on a path of completing the solution yourself. For algebraic manipulation solutions like this which don't lead to the actual result, it will be worth $0^+$. As such, can you try to finish out your solution?